# writing to securityfs file

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

I am new to the development, I have a task at hand to create a securityfs file and write some string to it via kernel security module.

I have created dir and a file in it with the following code.

```
test_dir = securityfs_create_dir("test", NULL);

basc_output_file = securityfs_create_file("basc_output_file",S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP, test, NULL, &test_measurements_file_ops);
```

But now I could not get any example or documentation how to write some string to that file. Any help ill be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is about how to implement the test_measurements_file_ops, I can provide following demo codes for your reference:

```
static const struct file_operations test_measurements_file_ops = {
    .write = test_write,
    .read  = test_read,
};

static ssize_t test_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
                            size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    char *data;
    int error;
    if (!count || count >= MAXIMUM_SIZE)
        return -ENOMEM;
    data = kzalloc(count + 1, GFP_NOFS);
    if (!data)
        return -ENOMEM;
    if (copy_from_user(data, buf, count)) {
        error = -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }

    /* handling kaddr */

out:
    kfree(data);
    return error ? error : count;
}

static ssize_t test_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, 
                            size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    void *kaddr;
    loff_t pos = *ppos;
    loff_t len = /* strlen(kernel strings need to be copied) */;

    if (pos >= len || !count)
        return 0;
    len -= pos;
    if (count < len)
        len = count;

    /* handling */

    if (copy_to_user(buf, kaddr, len))
        return -EFAULT;
    *ppos += len;
    return len;
}
```